# fastest way to serve angular 1.4 app?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am currently getting my head around how to serve an angular 1.4 app without all the concatenation/minification etc . In my current project we use grunt and the grunt serve option is bundling all the js/css together and I would like to see the 'as is' js files in the devtools. I tried to reconfigure the grunt serve but it looks too complicated. For example looks like the index.html file needs to be in the app folder for it too work but this is different in my project. How can I get it working or what other options( webpack ?) do I have?

Comment: Use VueJS and this as boilerplate: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews :)

Comment: you can use [GULP][1], with gulp-live-server ,is simple and clear, no need for webpack


  [1]: http://gulpjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

How about looking at generating source maps for your `.js` files - this will allow you to serve minified (as you would in production) and map to your source files, allowing you to debug through the unminifed code.

Take a look at the `grunt-contrib-concat` plugin - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat